# Clean and choose SQL string value

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database

I am ingested data associated to states which have various permutations associated to the state name. For example, in the table below, I could get a state name such as 'New Jersey' - which is correct, but I could also get a state name such as 'NewJersey'.

The issue: when ingesting the data from source, these values have different IDs. As a result, when working on transformations, both permutations are read.

| ID | State |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | New Jersey |
| 2 | NewJersey |

I would like to output the correct permutation name. For example, the final table should be as follows:

| ID | State |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | New Jersey |

Note: I have thought about identifying the string with the MAX length, but have not put this theory into practice yet.

I would really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Maybe create a table with all the permutations, assuming you know them all, and then join to that table on state. So New Jersey and NewJersey are set to an id of 1 in your permutation table.

Comment: Hi @Isolated I have tried to implement a mapping table, but this was unfortunately manual intensive. I also do not have access to source, and was not able to cater for all variations.

Comment: Assuming your data is as simple as your example (which seems unlikely), compare the strings with all spaces removed, then take the longest one.

Comment: Without knowing all the variations, I think it's going to be difficult to determine the correct transformation method. Sounds like you have occasions where "North" appears as "North", "N", "No", "Nrth", etc.

Comment: could you use soundex? https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_soundex.asp

Comment: @BryanDellinger I thought about that also but some states have the same soundex. South Carolina and South Virginia. There are a few others as well.

Comment: Data hygiene is a constant battle.  I would suggest getting a ZIP Code database where you can validate and normalize based on ZIP Code which is less likely to generate variations (other than honest typos) .

Comment: @BryanDellinger I tried the SOUNDEX function, but there are too many similar sounding words. I was perhaps thinking about the DIFFERENCE function and using that with the MAX length of a string.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I think that might be best. Based on the current scenario, a quick hack might not be a long term solution.

Comment: @sqlenthusiast I've seen downloads for free or even a nominal cost.   Either way, well worth the effort.   Otherwise you will be chasing ghosts for ever.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti agreed. I might be chasing this one for a while. I will have a look online for free copies. Thank you.

Comment: @sqlenthusiast I know I shouldn't do this, but I subscribe to zipcodedownload.com  .  As you know, ZIP Codes can change over time (added/deleted mostly).  They also give alternate City Names etc.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2a83e/5/0     Does this work?

Comment: Levenshtein Distance might help you to identify similar rows, but can be complex to implement on SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

As @Ullas mentioned in the comments, the below code gives your expected results.

```
insert into tb1 values
(1,'New Jersey'),
(2,'NewJersey'),
(3, 'NewYork'),
(4, 'New York'),
(5, 'California')
```

Get the row number by replacing the space between and order by State and length of state.

```
select ID, State from 
  (
  select *, row_number() over(partition by replace(State, ' ','') order by replace(State, ' ',''), len(State) desc) rn  from tb1 
  )a
where rn=1
order by 1
```

[image]